# Spine.js and jquerymobile-router

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, url-routing, spine.js

I'm trying to figure out how to use https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router in my Spine project. I'm not able to find any examples of how to integrate it into a Spine app.

I'm hoping someone has an example of how to use it with Spine.

Comment: +1 I'm interested in it too. I'm trying to build a test app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with this example: https://github.com/rbrcurtis/Spine-with-Jquery-Mobile it works great. I edited it a bit though. But it was a great start.

Answer (score 0):

There is another project to integrate jquery-mobile and Spine JS

https://github.com/lagartoflojo/spine.jqmobile

Comment: I didnt have much luck with that project.